# How can we represent SSL and Firewall in OSI Model?

Tags: tls, network, openssl

I want to draw an architecture diagram for a general ERP application.

In that I have come across a confusing point: where should I place the SSL and Firewall?

I tried to figure out exactly where the SSL and Firewall fit in the OSI Model. I know we can use Firewall in Application Layer, Network Layer, Transportation Layer, etc.

Comment: Many advanced networking components span several (and, in some cases, all) of the OSI layers. The OSI model is just a general guide for you to use for troubleshooting and problem analysis. Is there a particular problem you're trying to solve by figuring out which layers your devices/applications affect?

Comment: If you're looking at placing a firewall on the OSI for an ERP architecture diagram, you may have gotten lost somewhere along the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A firewall may work at different layers of the OSI model, going from layer 3 to layer 7 (depending on your firewall). Representing it in a diagram will require to set rules for each layer. I would represent the firewall and include a list of all enforced rules on each layer. Some examples could be:

- Layer 3: IP filtering
- Layer 4: port filtering (TCP/UDP)
- Layer 5: session layer firewall (state of the connection)
- Layer 6 and 7: application layer firewalls (more inteliggent, can perform deep packet inspection, close to IDS/IPS)

For the "SSL" I presume you mean an SSL offloader. SSL/TLS takes place at the presentation layer or layer 6 of the OSI model.

Comment: Thank you Lucas. I got what you said. I will try to design the diagram based on you comments. @Deer Hunter: Thanks for editing the post.